# How to forward URL to a different one?

Tags: dns

Is there any way to forward or shorten (example):

```
example.this.com/123/ABC
```

to

```
example.this.com/ABC
```

CName doesn't cut it, and I am not sure how to do a forward or url-shorten? I am not looking for `bit.ly` or those kinds of things. I would prefer to keep this done in house. Rewrite Rule in ISS would work too but I just don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that this is a wrong category but I have to post that I managed to write this and I want to share to help anyone else with the same problem.

I used URL Rewrite, which you can download and install on your IIS: [Video- What is URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-video-walkthrough)

Requested URL: Matches Pattern

Using: Regular Expressions

Pattern: `^([_0-9a-z-]+.aspx)`

Let me explain what this means:
 
`^` is anything before, 
`[_0-9a-z-]` is any character or number 
`.aspx` is not a pattern, this are those exact characters

Ignore case: checked

Action Type: rewrite

Rewrite URL: `example.this.com/ABC.aspx` (I oversimplified my example this is truly what I needed it for)

Append query string: checked

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to rewrite the Rules in the IIS server. 
Follow this [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) which gives detailed explanation on how to rewrite the Rules in IIS server

Comment: I am sorry but this does not fully answer my dilemma, great tutorial though! I will be using some sort of rewrite but what kind and how is the question.

Comment: I'm not expert to think what you are thinking and write answer according to that. Without explaining what you want exactly how are we supposed to write the answers?

Comment: Sorry, I did write what I needed to do and you sent a general tutorial to rewriting which does help in the fact that you pointed me in the right direction :)